# How can I browse StackOverflow although my network's having problems?

Tags: networking

I'm at work. Currently, we're having some **fierce** networking problems and every website I try to open throws an error similar to `Firefox can't find the server at www.google.com.`. However, I can still browse StackOverflow and I am posting this, which proves that I'm not reading from cache.

How is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like a problem for SuperUser.

Comment: Sounds like DNS issues.

Comment: Point your DNS at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and see what happens.

Comment: So now you've migrated the question from the one site he can still reach to one he can't. I understand the motivation, but realize that you didn't do him any favors.

Answer (score 4):

your network is experiencing DNS outage. SO name is still in the local DNS resolver cache.

Comment: Wow, what does it say about SO that he has SO in his DNS resolver cache, but not google????

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a DNS issue. Point your DNS at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific issue it sounds like @Franci Penov and @iftrue are right - you're having DNS issues.

On a more general level you should make sure you have some sort of connectivity in case your primary network goes down. This can be a separate connection (DSL + cable or dialup), a cell phone with a data plan and tethering, or the local coffee shop.

Answer (score 0):

`dig` is your friend here for analysing DNS issues. If you're a Windows man like me, you can get dig for Windows from [Nicholas Fong's site](http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/). (site also has basic user guide on it) - if you can't resolve it, the server's IP is 64.59.134.11 for your hosts file!

Find out the IP address of your primary DNS server then run

```
dig www.google.com. @ip.of.dns.server
```

If that yields something with

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.                    900     IN      SOA     a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com.
```

(or similar) in the results, then your DNS server's poorly. If you get a list of results in the ANSWER section including `www.google.com`, `www.l.google.com` and `www-tmmdi.l.google.com` (for example) then your DNS resolver is working and your own PC is not.

As others have said, try Google's DNS servers. Alternatively, try OpenDNS' servers: 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220. Best of luck...